# how can i add an array of post types to this query?

Tags: custom-post-types

`$pp = new WP_Query('orderby=comment_count&posts_per_page=4'); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pp = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'custom_type' ),
    'orderby' => 'comment_count',
    'posts_per_page' => 4
));
```